# Show alert when there's nothing to restore

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, restore

I have in-app purchases implemented in my app, along with restoring. My question is: if I press the restore button and there's nothing to restore, how can I know it?

Right now, if I tap the restore button and the user has purchased something before, it will restore and show a message. But if there's nothing to restore it doesn't do anything and I would like to tell the user something.

Thanks

**Update:**

I fixed it by checking the number of transactions made, if it was = 0 then there was nothing to restore:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
    NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (queue.transactions.count == 0) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You don't have anything to restore"  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alert show];

    }


    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {



        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
        [_transactionDelegate inAppPurchaseHelper:self transaction:productID didFinish:YES];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` method is called when the restore is completed. In the meantime, keep track of how many (if any) transactions you received with a type of `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`.

If it's zero then you know nothing was restored.

Comment: I can't get it to work..  I'm  using the InAppPurchaseHelper class, and I am restoring doing : `[[InAppPurchaseHelper sharedManager] restoreCompletedTransactionsBy:self] ;`

Comment: You need to update your question with relevant details of your issue. No one can help if you tell us nothing of what you are doing and simply state "it doesn't work".

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I didn't got what you said at first.